# Start up process for ejb jar failed due to no class definition found Websphere server

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, ibm-was

I am starting my application on Websphere server. Its showing the below exception

```
[8/29/14 1:51:13:709 GMT+05:30] 00000052 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: mdb.jar
[8/29/14 1:51:13:766 GMT+05:30] 00000052 EJBMDOrchestr E   CNTR0149E: The start up process for the mdb.jar enterprise bean in the CampTargetMDB module failed with the following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.common.message.Message
at java.lang.Class.getVirtualMethodsImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:925)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInit(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:1693)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.processBean(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:1344)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:2618)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3826)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1315)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:619)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:940)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4485)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4663)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)com.
```

Changes done
Lib folder is replaced with updated lib files

It was working before lib was replaced. And now it is not working even after placing the old lib files back

Kindly share some solutions

Comment: So where is the `com.common.message.Message` class? In a jar in a lib? Somewhere else?

Comment: class file is present in a jar file. Path of jar file is already added in shared lib path

Comment: Issue is working now after i have placed the old Jar files and class files. What i am not able to understand how to check if lib files and classes are corrupted  or not